# Optimizing codeigniter set_value together with value from database

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation, optimization

The aim and solution presented here is for a form input on a 'edit user page' in Codeigniter to return a validated value via set_value() if the form was submitted, and also to populate the field on the initial load if there is a value from the database.

I'm just wondering if there is a better way to optimize this long if-else, because i'm starting to find my page filled up with alot of the same code, which is a sign of violating DRY principles.

So what this does is basically on page load/reload, the first priority will always be to check if set_value exists, if it exists, that means the form was submitted but somehow there were errors, so we need to show the values that were submitted. Otherwise, we check if the value for the input exists from the populating, if it exists, we show it, otherwise we show a blank input.

```
<input type="text" name="fav_brands" value="<?=(set_value('fav_brands') ? set_value('fav_brands') : ($user_meta['fav_brands'] ? $user_meta['fav_brands'] : ''));?>"/>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: set_value uses a second argument to populate defaults when editing, set_value('fieldName', $fieldName);, and please do not use short-hand echos it's a bad practice.

Comment: Not answering your question, but you also need to consider how to display the POST data in the form if validation fails

Comment: ahmad: thanks, can't believe i totally forgot about the optional parameter.

Comment: whispersan: that's exactly what set_value() is for, in codeigniter.